# Intermittent network errors on Kubuntu 18.4 CLI

Tags: command-line, networking, kubuntu

After upgrading to Kubuntu 18.4 I'm getting network failures in command line programs like git or ping.

The upgrade process hung and I had to restart the notebook, but after the restart everything looked fine, except for this.

Errors are only noticeable in CLI programs.  Desktop programs seem to work fine.

```
sebas@sebas-HP:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS
Release:        18.04
Codename:       bionic
sebas@sebas-HP:~$ 
sebas@sebas-HP:~$ ping google.com
connect: the network is unreachable
sebas@sebas-HP:~$ ping google.com                                                                                                                                                            ⏎
PING google.com (172.217.28.174) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from eze03s29-in-f14.1e100.net (172.217.28.174): icmp_seq=1 ttl=54 time=9.19 ms
64 bytes from eze03s29-in-f14.1e100.net (172.217.28.174): icmp_seq=2 ttl=54 time=10.0 ms
^C
--- google.com ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 1001ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 9.199/9.634/10.069/0.435 ms
sebas@sebas-HP:~$ ping google.com
connect: the network is unreachable
sebas@sebas-HP:~$ ping google.com                                                                                                                                                            ⏎
PING google.com (172.217.28.174) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from eze03s29-in-f14.1e100.net (172.217.28.174): icmp_seq=1 ttl=54 time=17.4 ms
^C
--- google.com ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 17.406/17.406/17.406/0.000 ms
sebas@sebas-HP:~$ ping google.com
connect: the network is unreachable
sebas@sebas-HP:~$ ping google.com                                                                                                                                                            ⏎
PING google.com (172.217.28.174) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from eze03s29-in-f14.1e100.net (172.217.28.174): icmp_seq=1 ttl=54 time=9.34 ms
^C
--- google.com ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 9.348/9.348/9.348/0.000 ms
sebas@sebas-HP:~$ ping google.com
PING google.com (172.217.28.174) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from eze03s29-in-f14.1e100.net (172.217.28.174): icmp_seq=1 ttl=54 time=15.1 ms
64 bytes from eze03s29-in-f14.1e100.net (172.217.28.174): icmp_seq=2 ttl=54 time=10.0 ms
^C
--- google.com ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 1001ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 10.032/12.577/15.122/2.545 ms
sebas@sebas-HP:~$ ping google.com
connect: the network is unreachable
sebas@sebas-HP:~$ ping google.com                                                                                                                                                            ⏎
PING google.com (172.217.28.174) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from eze03s29-in-f14.1e100.net (172.217.28.174): icmp_seq=1 ttl=54 time=11.1 ms
^C
--- google.com ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 11.169/11.169/11.169/0.000 ms
sebas@sebas-HP:~$ ping google.com
connect: the network is unreachable
```

Is there any place where I can look for any misconfiguration I might have?

Comment: One of those times is 1001ms, which seems a bit high (mine is 6ms). Check /var/log/syslog for networking messages. If it's easily portable, try it on a different network to see if it's your system or a network issue.

Comment: `journalctl /usr/sbin/NetworkManager` will show you interesting log messages.

Comment: I switched to a different Wi-Fi network from a different ISP, and still see the same behavior.  Looks like something my Kubuntu is doing.

Comment: `journalctl /usr/sbin/NetworkManager` shows me messages about me connecting to a network and switching to another one (which I did manually and got logged) but nothing about the errors I'm having in between.

Answer (score 0):

I tried what user535733 suggested and checked `/var/log/syslog`.  There I found the error:

```
Dec 25 22:30:54 sebas-HP systemd-resolved[724]: Failed to open /etc/hosts: Permission denied
Dec 25 22:30:54 sebas-HP systemd-resolved[724]: Failed to start query: Permission denied
```

The thing is that I had /etc/hosts as a symlink to a file in my regular user home (because I wanted it versioned in git).

```
$ ls -la | grep hosts
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root  root       25 abr 26  2016 hosts -> /home/sebas/doc/prj/hosts
```

And in my prj folder:

```
$ ls -la | grep hosts
-rwxr--r--    1 sebas sebas      1758 oct 31  2017 hosts
```

Not sure if it's the symlink or the permissions that are causing the problem, but it never failed before the last system upgrade.

Anyway, restoring /etc/hosts as a regular file solved the issue.